# RuntimeWarning: Invalid value encountered in less xa[xa < 0] = -1 (Geopandas)

Tags: python, maps, geopandas

#### Problem

I'm trying to plot crime data in each district using **geopandas**. I have merged `shapefile` data and crime data:

```
merged = merged[['geometry','Extortion']]
merged.head()
```

[image: merged data]

#### Attempt

Then, I tried to plot crime data on top of the map:

```
variable = 'Extortion'
vmin, vmax = 120, 220
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20, 10))
merged.plot(variable, cmap='Blues', linewidth=0.8, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.8')
```

#### Error

```
C:\Users\Navoda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py:504: 
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
xa[xa < 0] = -1
```

Without the parameter 'variable', it loads to the base map. The problem is with the variable. I tried switching off warnings as most of the posts suggested. It still didn't load crime data.

I checked the error location. But, I couldn't figure out the reason.

#### Code

```
if xa.dtype.kind == "f":
        xa *= self.N
        # Negative values are out of range, but astype(int) would truncate
        # them towards zero.
        xa[xa < 0] = -1
        # xa == 1 (== N after multiplication) is not out of range.
        xa[xa == self.N] = self.N - 1
        # Avoid converting large positive values to negative integers.
        np.clip(xa, -1, self.N, out=xa)
        xa = xa.astype(int)
```

Note: Extortion column does not have `NaN` values.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `xa[xa < 0] = -1`? It's invalid syntax.

Comment: Do you have any negative values in your Extortion column?

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock it's not my code. It's particularly the location where error points to. It's in Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py:504

Comment: @martinfleis No there aren't any negative values. Extortion column has positive float values

Comment: @Pubz it seems to be an error in either GeoPandas or matplotlib. What are the versions you are using?

Comment: @martinfleis matplotlib 2.2.2 geopandas 0.4.1

Comment: Try updating matplotlib first. Current version is 3.0.3.

Comment: I updated matplotlib. But the issue persists. geopandas is up to date.

Comment: In that case I would check your data (but you said it should be okay) and then filled the issue here: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues . If your data column has only positive floats, it must be a bug.

Comment: Sort by the `Extortion` column and carefully check its values.  Are there any weird values?

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error and on examination it was caused by polygons in my shapefile not being represented in the data, so it just required replacement of the NANs which were created on the merge, eg

```
merged['Extortion']=merged['Extortion'].fillna(0)
```